# What is divergence and curl of vector $R \times (A \times R)$

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

What is divergence and curl of vector

$$R \times (A \times R),$$

where $R$ is radius vector and $A$ is constant vector. For divergence I tried to use $b(ac)-c(ab)$ identity, and used identity $\nabla \cdot (fA)$ where $A$ is vector and $f$ is scalar. But I got awrong answer. How do I expand divergence after $b(ac)-c(ab)$? 
UPD. So i guess i solved divergnce if only $(r\nabla)r=2r$

Comment: I edited your post to makke $\LaTeX$ work.  Hope I got it right!  Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried working it out by coordinates? $R = (x,y,z), A = (a_x, a_y, a_z)$? It might be a bit tedius, but you can have confidence you are doing it right.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf F &= \boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot \Big(\mathbf r \boldsymbol \times(\mathbf a \boldsymbol \times \mathbf r)\Big) \\
&= \boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot \Big((\mathbf r \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r)\mathbf a\boldsymbol -(\mathbf a \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r)\mathbf r\Big) \\
&= (\mathbf r \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r)\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf a + \boldsymbol \nabla(\mathbf r \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r) \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf a -(\mathbf a \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r)\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r - \boldsymbol \nabla(\mathbf a \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r)\boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r  \tag{$1$}\\
&= 0 + 2 \mathbf r \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf a - 3 \mathbf a \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r - \mathbf a \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r  \tag{$2$} \\
&= -2 \mathbf a \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r\\\\
\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times \mathbf F &= \boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times\Big(\mathbf r \boldsymbol \times(\mathbf a \boldsymbol \times \mathbf r\Big) \\
&= \boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times \Big((\mathbf r \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r)\mathbf a\boldsymbol -(\mathbf a \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r)\mathbf r\Big) \\
&= (\mathbf r \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r)\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times \mathbf a \boldsymbol + \boldsymbol \nabla(\mathbf r \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r) \boldsymbol \times \mathbf a \boldsymbol -(\mathbf a \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r)\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times \mathbf r \boldsymbol - \boldsymbol \nabla(\mathbf a \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r) \boldsymbol \times \mathbf r  \tag{$3$}\\
&= \mathbf 0 \boldsymbol+ 2\mathbf r \boldsymbol \times \mathbf a \boldsymbol-\mathbf 0 \boldsymbol- \mathbf a \boldsymbol \times\mathbf r  \tag{$4$}\\
&= -3\mathbf a \boldsymbol \times \mathbf r,
\end{align*}
where

- $(1)$ follows since $\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot (\mathbf F + \mathbf G) = \boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf F + \boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf G$ and $\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot (\phi \mathbf F) = \phi \boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf F + \boldsymbol \nabla \phi \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf F$;
- $(2)$ follows since $\begin{aligned}[t]&\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r = \boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot (x,y,z)=3, \\ &\boldsymbol \nabla(\mathbf a \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r) = \boldsymbol \nabla(a_1x + a_2y+a_3y)=(a_1,a_2,a_3)=\mathbf a, \text{ and}\\ &\boldsymbol \nabla(\mathbf r \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf r) = \boldsymbol \nabla\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right) = (2x,2y,2z)=2\mathbf r;\end{aligned}$
- $(3)$ follows since $\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times (\mathbf F + \mathbf G) = \boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times \mathbf F + \boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times \mathbf G$ and $\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times (\phi \mathbf F) = \phi \boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times \mathbf F + \boldsymbol \nabla \phi \boldsymbol \times \mathbf F$; and
- $(4)$ follows since $\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times \mathbf r = \boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times(x,y,z)=\mathbf 0$.